# Is it possible to search a table in reverse to get latest data quickly?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a table with several million records.

The table has a long string as a key, and searching for records, especially new ones, is very slow.

I have tried to narrow the search to `whereDate >= this week`, or `whereID >= 999999` but this doesn't give a huge performance boost.

We are using Laravel. Is there some kind of feature to search a table from the bottom up or in reverse, instead of searching incrementally from the top down? Something like `Model::findBackwards($key)` that would start looking at the most recent record and process backwards would be ideal in this situation.

How would you approach this problem?

Edit - here is our current query. It's a job running on horizon

```
if (DB::table('big_table_with_a_stupid_key')
    ->whereDate('created_at', '>=', '2019-11-10')
    ->where('hash', $this->hash)
    ->increment('counter')
);

else {
    DB::table('big_table_with_a_stupid_key')->where(['hash' => $this->hash])->increment('counter');
}
```

Comment: `ORDER BY col ASC / DESC` in plain mysql queries, so it's definitely possible.

Comment: What is your definition of `latest data`? As a quick solution I would suggest implementing a `lastModified` column and sorting by that

Comment: `$table->index('yourKeyColumn');`

Comment: We have data spanning years, so anything in the last 24-48 hours would be ideal to optimize this lookup query

Comment: sounds like you need proper indexing and actual sql queries instead of working through some intermediate wrapper for it.

Comment: What is your model definition file looks like? Share the fragment where you declare your `ID` column or `date` column.

Comment: "How would you approach this problem?" - Identify the slow query and add an index. So what exactly is the slow query?

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. Updated the question with the query. Also updated the code with a proper index, but still 50,000 jobs stuck on the queue we need to get through first

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reverse order of the result, you can use latest() function.

Laravel documentation says: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries

> latest / oldest
>
> The latest and oldest methods allow you to easily order results by date. By default, result will be ordered by the created_at column. Or, you may pass the column name that you wish to sort by:

```
$user = DB::table('users')->latest()->first(); // order by created_at
$user = DB::table('users')->latest('id')->first(); // order by id
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to do this by using the `ORDER BY` clause in your underlying database query.  Laravel (of course) exposes this with `->orderBy()`

https://www.tutorialsplane.com/laravel-order-by-asc-desc/

The SQL engine will place the result rows in the requested sequence before returning them to you.

Then, to address your performance issues, be sure that any column that you routinely use for searching has an *index.*  This is the secret to maintaining good performance as the number of rows increases.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I considered this, but when dealing with millions of rows, it is efficient to order them and then search? Is there not a way to search backwards?